# JSON: передача данных (php->ajax)

Tags: ajax, php

Приветствую всех.

Допустим, я хочу выводить все ошибки, которые мы получили в PHP файле в результате обработки ajax запроса.

```
$idx = 0;
$array = array();
if( !idx )
    $array[0] = "error";
```

Как правильно все это осуществить, чтобы ajax читал ошибки и выводил их?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

[`AJAX`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) ничего читать не будет - это такой подход, а не чёртик в компьютере. Выполняете запрос к серверу, получаете ответ. Если есть ошибки выводите их.

`$array['0']` - это какой-то тихий ужас. Уже напишите одно из двух:

```
$array[]  = ..;
$array[0] = ..;
```

Comment: $.ajax({
    url: "engine.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        $("#errors").html(data);
    }
});  

$arr = array('1', '2');
echo json_encode($arr); 

Не подскажите, что не так?

Comment: Вы пробовали это выполнить? Пытаетесь подсунуть массив методу [``.html()``](http://api.jquery.com/html/) - получаете ошибку.  
Сделайте лучше ``console.log(data)`` и посмотрите получаете ли вы то, что хотите. Если да, то выводите массив построчно или примените [``.join()``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), например.

А еще, на стороне сервера стоило бы сделать:

    header('Content-type: application/json');